# MySQL cursor UPDATE LOOP

Tags: mysql

I normally try to figure things out on my own, but I'm stumped on this.

I have leads in one SugarCRM account that I want to reassign a specific number to each active user. Every time I try to run this I keep getting "ERROR 1064 (42000):... at Line 4" and I have no idea what is wrong.

This is what I have made so far:

Hello, I normally try to figure things out on my own, but I'm stumped on this.

I have leads in one SugarCRM account that I want to reassign a specific number to each active user. Every time I try to run this I keep getting "ERROR 1064 (42000):... at Line 4" and I have no idea what is wrong.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  assign_leads $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE assign_leads(num_rows INT)
    BEGIN
    SET num_rows = num_rows;
    DECLARE i VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN;         
    DECLARE employee_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT users.id
        FROM users
        WHERE (((users.title)="South Carolina Qualifier") AND ((users.status)="Active"));

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

    OPEN employee_cursor;
    employee_loop: LOOP

    FETCH  employee_cursor INTO i;

        SET @sql_text1 = concat('UPDATE leads SET assigned_user_id = ',@i,' WHERE ((assigned_user_id IS NULL OR assigned_user_id = '1' OR assigned_user_id =  '') AND do_not_call = '0' AND deleted = '0' AND status = 'New') LIMIT ',@num_rows,' 1;')
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;


         IF exit_loop THEN
            CLOSE employee_cursor;
              LEAVE employee_loop;
         END IF;
  END LOOP employee_loop;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations:

- `SET` must be located after the `DECLARE`:

```sql
...
    CREATE PROCEDURE assign_leads(num_rows INT)
    BEGIN
    -- SET num_rows = num_rows;
    DECLARE i VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN;         
    DECLARE employee_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT users.id
        FROM users
        WHERE (((users.title)="South Carolina Qualifier") AND ((users.status)="Active"));

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;
    SET num_rows = num_rows;
    OPEN employee_cursor;
...
```

This assignment (`SET`) does not make much sense, it assigns the value of `num_rows` parameter to the same `num_rows` parameter.

- Must escape some characters from your `@sql_text1` variable and add `;` at the end of the statement:

```sql
...
/*
SET @sql_text1 = concat('
  UPDATE leads SET assigned_user_id = ',@i,'
   WHERE (
          (assigned_user_id IS NULL OR assigned_user_id = '1' OR assigned_user_id =  '') AND
          do_not_call = '0' AND deleted = '0' AND status = 'New'
         )
   LIMIT ',@num_rows,' 1;
')
*/

SET @sql_text1 = concat('
  UPDATE leads SET assigned_user_id = ',@i,'
   WHERE (
          (assigned_user_id IS NULL OR assigned_user_id = \'1\' OR assigned_user_id =  \'\') AND
          do_not_call = \'0\' AND deleted = \'0\' AND status = \'New\'
         )
   LIMIT ',@num_rows,' 1;
');
...
```

- `@i` and `@num_rows` are [9.4. User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), `i` is one [13.6.4.1. Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html) and `num_rows` is a routine parameter, are different variables.

Comment: I have chenged the query and it now accepts the stored procedure, but when I try to use the procedure, CALL assign_leads(100) it results in ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: @JoshS: Check the query (variable `@sql_text1`) before executing. `SELECT \`@sql_text1\`;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query...

```
      DELIMITER $$
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  assign_leads $$

  CREATE PROCEDURE assign_leads(num_rows INT)
      BEGIN
      DECLARE i VARCHAR(255);
      DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN;         
      DECLARE employee_cursor CURSOR FOR
          SELECT users.id
          FROM users
          WHERE (((users.title)="South Carolina Qualifier") AND((users.status)="Active"));

      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;
      OPEN employee_cursor;

  employee_loop: LOOP
  FETCH  employee_cursor INTO i;
  SET @sql_text1 = concat('
  UPDATE leads SET assigned_user_id = ',@i,' 
  WHERE (
  (assigned_user_id IS NULL OR assigned_user_id = \'1\' OR assigned_user_id =  \'\') AND
```

do_not_call = \'0\' AND deleted = \'0\' AND status = \'New\'
      ) LIMIT ',@num_rows,' 1;'
      );
      PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_text1;
      EXECUTE stmt1;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

```
  IF exit_loop THEN
  CLOSE employee_cursor;
  LEAVE employee_loop;
  END IF;
  END LOOP employee_loop;
   END $$
    DELIMITER ;enter code here
```